# my desktop seems to be outside of my 40`` tv in 1920x1080?

Tags: resolution

My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop seems to be outside of my 40" TV in 1920x1080! If I select a lower resolution like 1366x768 it is ok.

What is the problem here and how can I set up my system to see the full desktop in the high resolution?

Comment: ...for some resaon a cant access the tv`s screen adjustements but i think you solved this.

Comment: If the below answer helped you, please don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the abysmally small number at the left of the text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have "overscanning" enabled on your TV you will need to disable it.  Otherwise sometimes there is a zoom feature.  TVs use it to help make DVDs look better on your TV but it does mess up desktops.  I had the same problem on my Toshiba and my mint/Kodi mediaserver.

Try looking in the setting for Overscan or zoom and see if that helps.